# how to be sure its parallel in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parallel-processing, task

This is  the code i have written now a days, i want to know does it really running in parallel .
this is part of a controller in my mvc code.

```
namespace NewsReader.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var categoryList = db.Categories.Select(item => item.Name).ToList();
                var khabaronline = KhabarOnlineTask(categoryList);
                var isna = IsnaTask(categoryList);
                await Task.WhenAll(khabaronline, isna);
                var newsList = new List<NewsDetail>();
                newsList.AddRange(khabaronline.Result);
                newsList.AddRange(isna.Result);
                return View(newsList);
            }
       }

       public Task<List<NewsDetail>> KhabarOnlineTask(List<string> categoryList) 
       { 
          var ac = new AgenciesClass(); 
          return Task.Run(() => ac.KhabarOnline(categoryList)); 
       }
```

Comment: There are two huge functions that are downloading images and context from two different sites. they are simple methods of c# without any await and sync . i made these two methods as isnatask and khabaronlinetask, they are just like below :

                public Task<List<NewsDetail>> KhabarOnlineTask(List<string> categoryList )
        {
            var ac = new AgenciesClass();
            return Task.Run(() => ac.KhabarOnline(categoryList));
        }

Comment: Then you need to show the code for those methods, or at least the part that you believe makes them run in parallel. Preferably in an edit to your question.

Comment: Here's some documentation you can review `Using an Asynchronous Controller in ASP.NET MVC`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @mohammaddarbanbaran - when adding code make sure to edit your post and add it there instead of comments - code in comments is not readable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both tasks look similarly code indeed will try to run in parallel as result of synchronously starting 2 tasks with `Task.Run(()...`. They may endup serializing each other due to bugs in implementation/explicit synchronization, but at least start would be in parallel.

`await Task.WhenAll` will guarantee that code continues only after both tasks are completed.

Note: code that consistently uses `async`/`await` or just lower level Run/ContinueWith would be easier to read/reason about, but mixing the way you did it is fine too.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about parallel programming but showing an async method. Although they are similar in idea they have several differences. Look into TPL (task parallel library) if you are trying to run code in parallel. Otherwise as it is in you example your code will run asynchronously and will only only spawn a new thread if needed.

```
List<string> collection = GetSomeCollection();
Parallel.ForEach(collection, item =>
{
    //run in parallel
});
```

Comment: I think your suggestion to switch to TPL is somewhat unrelated based on usage of `Task.WhenAll` in OP's sample...

Comment: It wasn't a suggestion to switch to TPL. The OP was asking about running the code in parallel but has an example of asynchronous code.